# What are the deciding factors for choosing a ORM

Tags: java, sql, database, orm, data-access-layer

What are the deciding factors for choosing a ORM or going for a custom Data Object Model.

When is better to go for a custom Data Access Layer and when is it better to go for an ORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first list all criteria's (factors) that are important, relevant to the  project, and then see what solution better fits in to my list.